# Cosa sono i "calzoni a gamba"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Una ragazza, sola in fondo alla spiaggia. Zazzera bionda e **calzoni a gamba**, veniva dalla nostra parte.

Questa espressione, "calzoni a gamba", appare di nuovo un po' più avanti nel libro:

> «No, no, le cose stanno cambiando, caro Massimo, non si può più venire da queste parti. Appena ti volti vedi gente coi cappellini da fantino, mamme e figlie col culo a terra e i **calzoni a gamba**. E i guagliòni che vengono fuori ora, quelli mi fanno ridere, con la camicia rosso fuoco aperta fino all’ombelico, una finta sicurezza, timidi ed esibizionisti, [...]»

Non sono riuscita a trovare questa locuzione, "calzoni a gamba", su nessun dizionario, ma curiosamente appare nella [definizione dell'espressione "alla cacciatora" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cacciatora/):

> Si dice in partic. dei vestiti che indossano usualmente i cacciatori, per lo più di velluto a coste: i **calzoni a gamba**, da portare con gli stivaloni, la giacca (*giacca alla c.*, ma anche semplicem. *cacciatora* s. f.) con martingala e tasche laterali coperte, o posteriori, per la selvaggina; [...].

L'ho trovata anche nel libro  [*Ribelli e dannati*](https://books.google.es/books?id=Ka60DAAAQBAJ&pg=PT43&lpg=PT43&dq=%22calzoni+a+gamba%22&source=bl&ots=0pSMQ1DQk5&sig=ACfU3U3S6vRD1qRr5_loGdX-r-Bm1-H1lQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLxtKFxMPrAhWoA2MBHfqqAKoQ6AEwC3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22calzoni%20a%20gamba%22&f=false), di Teodora Oliva:

> Alcuni indossavano vestiti di panno nero con cappelli a larga tesa, ornati di
> nastro rosso, altri portavano il costume caratteristico dei contadini meridionali con **calzoni a gamba**, cappello a cono, e giubbetto colorato, con immancabili mantelli di lana, di colore bigio e nero.

E sulla [*Biblioteca delle tradizioni popolari siciliane*, vol. XIV](https://www.forgottenbooks.com/es/download/UsieCostumiCredenzeePregiudizidelPopoloSiciliano_10404909.pdf), di Giuseppe Pitrè, in una descrizione delle maschere di Carnevale tradizionali della Sicilia si legge (il grassetto è sempre mio):

> Il *Dutturi* veste poco dissimile al Barone: nicchio in capo, colletto che nasconde le orecchie cravattone che copre il petto, panciotto che scende fino alle anguinaglie, livrea, **calzoni a gamba**
> (*causi a gammigghia*), scarpine.

Sulla [biblioteca "Internet Archive"](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%22calzoni%20a%20gamba%22&sin=TXT) se ne possono trovare altre occorrenze. Una è questa descrizione dell'uniforme di uno dei corpi dei soldati pontifici, apparsa nella [*Lettura*, rivista mensile del Corriere della sera](https://archive.org/details/laletturarivis1908milauoft/page/656/mode/2up?q=%22calzoni+a+gamba%22) all'inizio del XX secolo:

> Dinanzi agli appartamenti del Pontefice si scorgono le
> guardie nobili, elegantissime, con l'elmetto d'argento, l'uniforme blu a falde, i **calzoni a gamba** di panno candido e gli stivaloni alla scudiera.

Partendo dell'espressione siciliana che appare nel libro di Pitrè, "causi a gammigghia", sul [*Vocabolario siciliano etimologico, italiano, e latino*, dell'abate Michele Pasqualino](https://books.google.es/books?id=2G2Iy-2FxDEC&pg=PA198&lpg=PA198&dq=%22a+gammigghia%22&source=bl&ots=tR9ixugmvi&sig=ACfU3U3p6O-_MVBZUVNuz-ZKG6iuZ8M2oA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0jOCc8YjsAhUF5uAKHTx7AkYQ6AEwAnoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22a%20gammigghia%22&f=false) ho trovato:

> Gammigghia, cintolino da legare sotto il ginocchio i calzoni, *cintolino*, zonula fibularis genu.

Quindi, potrebbe trattarsi di calzoni legati sotto il ginocchio con tale cintolino? Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire l'espressione "calzoni a gamba"?

Comment: Sono calzoni che arrivano all’altezza del ginocchio. Forse più comunemente conosciuti come pantaloni alla zuava https://www.alpenclassics.it/uomo/pantaloni-bermuda/pantaloni-al-ginocchio/6900/pantalone-trachten-in-pelle-con-cintura-sigmar3-havanna?sPartner=26&number=AC_Sigmar3havanna-48&utm_source=google-it&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=AC_Sigmar3havanna-48&utm_campaign=google-it&gclid=EAIaIQobChMImeXI1rT96wIVB9-yCh1yfA9yEAQYASABEgLt8fD_BwE

Comment: Se ne parla anche sul [forum di WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/calzoni-a-gamba.1406657/), ma non si arriva a nessuna conclusione affidabile. Veramente non si trova da nessuna parte una spiegazione su cosa siano questi "calzoni a gamba" :( :(   (Francamente, una risposta che afferma che erano pantaloni usati dalle ragazze nel medioevo...).

Comment: Da “La Briganta”. *Con un'ampia fascia rossa fermai in cintura i calzoni a gamba di foggia antiquata che mi arrivavano appena sopra il polpaccio.* https://books.google.it/books?id=jKKiCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT28&dq=%22calzoni+a+gamba%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD1Orth4nsAhVQ_SoKHSuaBYMQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22calzoni%20a%20gamba%22&f=false

Comment: Da “101 cose..” *Per cui porto scarpe ricercate, calzoni a gamba corta, e un sacco di vestiti, per dare a queste mie caviglie un ruolo da protagoniste nella mia vita,* https://books.google.it/books?id=l6BJCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&dq=%22calzoni+a+gamba%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD1Orth4nsAhVQ_SoKHSuaBYMQ6AEwAnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22calzoni%20a%20gamba%22&f=false

Comment: Ma, @Hachi, "calzoni a gamba corta" non sarebbero pantaloni corti? A parte questo, da tutto il resto, mi sembra credibile che si tratti di pantaloni legati appena sotto il ginocchio, ma qualcuno dovrebbe scrivere una risposta un po' più precisa di quella esistente, in cui mi sembra leggere che si tratti di pantaloni medioevali usati sia da ragazzi che da ragazze.

Comment: Penso che “calzoni a gamba”  stia per “calzoni a gamba   corta” come riportato sopra e come si può desumere da altri esempi in  quanto per un paio di pantaloni si intende comunemente “a gamba lunga.”